# Zoho Recruit API redirecting to their homepage

Tags: php, html, json, zoho

I'm having trouble getting the Zoho Recruit API to work properly.  I haven't found any good documentation, so I've been going on the documentation here: https://www.zoho.com/recruit/api.html

My URL is: http://home.pointybracket.net/zoho/index.php

My code is: http://pastebin.com/neyTBR8h

My boss wants to know if I can integrate a clients job openings hosted on zoho recruit, into their website.  So luckily, Zoho recruit offers an API.  I've been trying to run a test here to see roughly what this job would entail, and what to charge the client, but I'm running into problems.

When I visit my test page (noted above as the URL), if I'm currently logged into zoho recruit in my browser, it redirects the page to https://recruit.zoho.com/recruit/ShowHomePage.do

If I'm not logged in, it simply displays this page (https://recruit.zoho.com/recruit/ShowHomePage.do) within my own (like it actually loads the content of this page into my page, so I'm still on my page, but it doesn't list the test job that I've added.).

My hopes are that somehow I can get data returned to my php script, so I can format the open jobs in HTML and echo them onto the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that the official documentations for the Zoho Recruit API was actually wrong.  Docs: https://www.zoho.com/recruit/get-records.html

So the URL they say to use:

```
http://recruit.zoho.com/ats/private/json/Module/getRecords?authtoken=Auth Token&scope=recruitapi
```

The correct URL replaces "ats" with "recruit", becoming:

```
http://recruit.zoho.com/recruit/private/json/Module/getRecords?authtoken=Auth Token&scope=recruitapi
```

After I had changed the URL, I'm finally receiving json data from Zoho Recruits servers.

Hope this might help someone else.

Comment: tried using this.. now I'm getting error 3602: ERROR_URL_RULE_NOT_CONFIGURED

Comment: APIs have a tendency to change.  This was so long ago.  Try following the official docs.